# Sum of columns in 2d jagged arrays with a void method,no return

Tags: java, arrays

i was wondering how i could change my current code which at the moment will sum up only complete columns and the rest it would catch the exception and not print it. I want it to add up the columns no matter how many numbers are there. For example

1 2 3 4

1 2 3

1 2

1

I would want it to add those up meaning 4, 6, 6, 4 does anyone know how to do so?

```
 public static void sumByCol(int[][] matrix){
  try {      
  for(int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++){
        int total = 0;
        // hol a column constant and loop over each row
        for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
            total += matrix[row][col];
 }
      System.out.println("Sum for col " + col + " is " + total);   
 }
}
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i get out of bounds error

Comment: That is if i remove the try catch

Comment: Take a look at my solution below. It is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work with `try-catch`, you'd have to put it inside the nested `loop`. But it's not a very nice solution.

Much better would be to simply check if the array contains the index you're going to access, that is

```
for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++)
    if (col < matrix[row].length)
        total += matrix[row][col];
```

To fix the problem when your first row doesn't contain the maximum number of columns, you need to find the max number first, e.g.

```
int maxColumns = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    if (matrix[i].length > maxColumns)
        maxColumns = matrix[i].length;
```

And then use `maxColumns` in your second `loop` to iterate through columns `0..maxColumns`, i.e.

```
for(int col = 0; col < maxColumns ; col++){
```

Comment: I dont need it to work with the try catch i just want it to be able to add all the columns up regardless of size

Comment: @JimBob101 The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown because you access elements that don't exist. Ignoring it doesn't really fix the root cause. To fix the root cause you need to access only those elements that **do** exist - which is what my answer suggests.

Comment: Correct your answer works for that example, i tried it on other arrays and it didnt work for example i tried it on this one  int[][] matrix1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                      {1, 2, 3},
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                      {1, 2},
                      {1}};

Comment: Well ok, but that's just another bug in **your** original code ;) Since you iterate on column `0 .. matrix[0].length`. To fix the case you just mentioned, you need to iterate through the whole matrix first, finding the maximum number of columns. I can update my answer.

Comment: @JimBob101 I've updated my answer to handle the case you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to use:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[][]{{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2},{1}};
String end = "";
boolean check = false;
int j = 0;
do{
    check = false;
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        if (j+1 < matrix[i].length){
            check = true;
        }
        if (j < matrix[i].length){
            total += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    end += total + " ";
    j++;
}while (check);
```

What this does is it takes the value of `matrix[0][0]`, `matrix[1][0]`, `matrix[2][0]`... etc. and adds them, stores it in a String 'end' with a space, and then moves on to the next column.

No 'try-catch' is needed, as it will never go outside of the array. The first 'if' statement will keep the 'do-while' loop running as long as there is another column.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is similar to finding the sum of each row. However to find the sum of each column, we need to know the maximum number of columns in your jagged 2D array:

```
int maxCol = 0;         
for(int x=0; x<nums.length; x++)
    if(nums[x].length > maxCol)
        maxCol = nums[x].length;
```

After knowing the maximum number of columns, a pair of nested loops will be enough to sum the columns. I used an `if statement` to ensure I stay within array bounds:

```
for(int y=0; y<maxCol; y++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<nums.length; x++)
        if(y < nums[x].length)
            sum += nums[x][y];      
    System.out.println("Sum of col " + y + ": " + sum);     
}
```

---

## Code Testing 1:

```
int[][] nums = {{1,2,3,4},
                {1,2,3},
                {1,2},
                {1}};
```

**Output:**

```
Sum of col 0: 4
Sum of col 1: 6
Sum of col 2: 6
Sum of col 3: 4
```

---

## Code Testing 2:

```
int[][] nums = {{1},
                {1,2},
                {1,2,3},
                {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}};
```

**Output:**

```
Sum of col 0: 4
Sum of col 1: 6
Sum of col 2: 6
Sum of col 3: 4
Sum of col 4: 5
Sum of col 5: 6
Sum of col 6: 7
```